# Continuous Date Span T-Sql

Tags: teradata

I am trying to combine continuous date spans whenever they exist

```
ID_NBR  START_DT    END_DT
22  20120101    20120131
22  20120201    20120731
22  20120801    20121231
22  20130201    20131231
22  20140101    20151231
22  20160101    20160131
22  20160201    20160430
22  20160601    20160630
22  20160701    99991231
```

and want the result to be like below:

```
ID_NBR  START_DT    END_DT
22  20120101    20121231
22  20130201    20160430
22  20160601    99991231
```

Obviously I'm not trying to be spoon-fed so here is what I have so far but I really think there has to be an simpler way

```
SELECT 
    s1.ID_NBR,
    s1.START_DT, 
    MIN(t1.END_DT) AS END_DT,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY s1.START_DT) AS Sequence_ID
FROM MEM s1 
INNER JOIN MEM t1 
ON t1.ID_NBR=s1.ID_NBR
AND s1.START_DT <= t1.END_DT
AND NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT*FROM  MEM t2 
                        WHERE t2.ID_NBR=t1.ID_NBR
                                AND (t1.END_DT+1) >= t2.START_DT 
                                AND t1.END_DT < t2.END_DT
                ) 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM MEM s2 
WHERE s2.ID_NBR=s1.ID_NBR
AND s1.START_DT > s2.START_DT AND (s1.START_DT-1) <= s2.END_DT)                 
GROUP BY s1.ID_NBR,s1.START_DT
```

Comment: what's the date type of Stat_DT and END_DT?

Comment: how you got the result set? What is the logic?

Comment: Decimal(38,0) and thanks for the edit

Comment: Which version of sql server you are using?

Comment: Kannan the logic is to combine spans for the same ID ex 20150101 to 20150131 and next record 20150201 to 20150228 instead of 2 records it would be 20150101 to 20150228

Comment: Teradata 14.10.0607  14.10.06.07

Comment: Then why it is tagged to sql-server ?

Comment: Kannan not sure it might have been tagged by EricZ as he did a format to the question

Comment: I'm not sure how you can work with these date fields stored as decimal values and then add/delete days and expect calendaring functions to get applied, but what I usually do is add another column after end_dt called something like 'expectedNextDay' which is one day after the end.  Then you can test for overlaps with a self-join.

Comment: Are you sure those columns are DECIMALs instead of DATE? Your current logic will not work as expected. You can utilize an OLAP-function to compare the prvious row's value. If your running TD14.10 the best solution will be based on a `SELECT NORMALIZE`.

Comment: For now they are Decimals, I can convert them to Dates. Would you be able to share your logic with what is given above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Teradata TD14.10 there's a simple way to combine overlapping periods using `SELECT NORMALIZE`. The implementation is based on the `PERIOD` data type, which includes the start date, but excludes the end date. As your data includes the end date you must adjust it for the calculation and again to split the period in separate columns again:

```
SELECT ID_NBR,
   Begin(pd), -- get the start date
   Last(pd)   -- adjust the end date
FROM
 (
   SELECT NORMALIZE 
      ID_NBR, 
      -- periods are [inclusive..exclusive[ 
      PERIOD(START_DT,CASE WHEN END_DT = DATE '9999-12-31' THEN END_DT ELSE END_DT + 1 END) AS pd
   FROM tab
 ) AS dt
```

If you dates are actually `Decimal(38,0)` (which is quite wrong) you need to cast them to dates first using

```
Cast(start_dt - 19000000 AS DATE)
```